# Ubuntu 13.04 Login Loop

Tags: login

I have a problem with Ubuntu **13.04**.

I cannot log in to my account. I put the right password but there is an endless loop. (if i put wrong pass, it says "Invalid password..."). Also, it doesnt show the small drop down menu with choices "Gnome fallback, Default, etc.."

If i login as guest, the desktop is clear, no bars, no menus, anything. Just right clicks works only.

I have already try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-12-10-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) solution ( `chown username:username .Xauthority` ) but there is no "Xauthority" at ubuntu 13.04. (?)

Is the problem about lightdm?
Also, i tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` but it soesn't work.

I use the recovery mode (root command shell or something like this) in order to try the above commands.

Has anyone a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: I found shep's answer to be the most helpful here, and it's got negative votes. Perhaps some others should vote that puppy up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting `$HOME/.profile`, I had the same problem before, because I added a function into `$HOME/.profile`.

When I deleted the function, I could login again. 
The original content of `$HOME/.profile` is

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: Is this safe? If i delete '$HOME/.profile' will create any problem?

Comment: That's OK,or you can make the content of `$HOME/.profile` be default.

Comment: This was my solution. I had added a function to my `.profile`, and commenting that out did the trick. So I guess I need to put them in my `.bashrc`? Whacky.

Answer (score 2):

The file you need to make your own again is `/home/[yourUsername]/.Xauthority` (the `.` is important!).
 And be sure to follow the procedure in [the first solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/223634/117103)

Comment: I think there is no .Xauthority file. (?)
http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/3639/4z6w.jpg

Comment: @Fotis you are looking at /root, there will indeed be no such file, look into your own home folder as stated above.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but neither changing the ownership of ~/.Xauthority nor commenting the content of ~/.profile made a difference. To fix it I did the following

```
rm ~/.Xauthority
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg
sudo reboot
```

It took a little longer than normal to login, but I was able to. My guess is that the .Xauthority file became corrupted in some way.

Comment: Ah. For me, I had ssh'd into the machine from two different machines simultaneously, both with X11 forwarding. This fixed it! Also, I had set it up to not ask for my password and log me straight in; performing these fixes restored it to this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

lightdm may be a good place to look. I had a similar problem in 12.04LTS and discovered a problem with Cairo-dock. Here's what I did:

boot
login   ->returns to lightdm login prompt

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>   ->gets you to shell

```
sudo more /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
```

mine showed an error loading cairo-dock, followed by a couple of errors. You may get a different error, but it'll point you where to look next