# Only Guest session can be started

Tags: 13.10, lightdm, upstart, plymouth

While Ubuntu is starting, the following messages are shown and stays shown for long time:

```
* Starting LightDM Display Manager                                      [OK]
* Stopping Send an event to indicate plymouth is up                    [OK]
* Starting startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop   [OK]
* Stopping startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop   [OK]
```

After reaching the login page and attempting to login, the same messages are shown again, then I'm returned to the login page to choose between my my username and a Guest session. If I choose a Guest session, everything goes ok and I login as a Guest.

I tried restarting the machine, and then new, but similar messages appeared:

```
* Starting LightDM Display Manager                                      [OK]
* Stopping Send an event to indicate plymouth is up                    [OK]
* Starting startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop   [OK]
* Stopping startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop   [OK]
* Starting Mount network filesystems                                    [OK]
* Stopping Mount network filesystems                                    [OK]
* Stopping Send an event to indicate plymouth is up                    [OK]
* Starting startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop   [OK]
```

And the same scenario is repeated. I can login only using a Guest session. If I use my user, I'm shown these messages, but this time, it took a very long time and I wasn't shown the login page again, so I had to restart my machine.

The thing I can remember that could be causing a problem, is that I added a path to the PATH environment variable in the `~/.pam_environment` file. But I remember it was written ok:

```
PATH=/my/path:${PATH}
```

And while Ubuntu was starting, I connected my external screen. Could any of this be a cause to this problem ? What is the problem in the first place ?!

I'm using Dell Inspiron 7520 SE.

Comment: Did you tried http://askubuntu.com/q/223501/169736 or http://askubuntu.com/q/314362/169736

Comment: Thanks a million man. None of these solutions were feasible because the system is still fresh (2 days old), but the Alt+number (i.e. Alt+3) trick enabled me to reach my .pam_environment file and remove the file I added earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know much about pam and its path variables

But If you think adding the path is the cause then just go to **recovery mode** and and *remove the PATH which you added recently*..If that is the cause then after changing it your ubuntu should behave properly...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Frankly I doubt it is. How can I go to recovery mode ?

Comment: During the booting time you can see the entry for recovery mode in GRUB menu..If you are not getting grub menu then keep pressing `shift` after starting the computer

Comment: Thanks mate :). I didn't actually use the recovery mode feature, but I was able to reach my .pam_environment file by pressing Alt+3 and logging in from the command line.

Comment: That doesn't matter much! ;) The important thing is that your problem is solved now!