# Login Screen on 13.10 keeps looping back to login (XOrg/NVIDIA problem?)

Tags: lightdm

Upgraded from 12.04 to 13.10. Seemed to go OK, but when rebooted the login screen was very low resolution with trailing mouse, so purged the Nvidia drivers, then reinstalled via PPA as in [www.howopensource.com](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-nvidia-geforce-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/)

Seemed to go OK (no screen errors, the login screen is now normal resolution) but when I login it loops back after a minute to the login screen again.

I can login using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

The Guest account has same problem.

Removed `.XAuthority` and reinstalled XOrg as mentioned here: [Ubuntu 13.04 Login Loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314362/ubuntu-13-04-login-loop)

Installed GDM as here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/130387/stuck-at-login-screen but it failed to load (could only login into TTY)

Errors in `Xorg.0.log`:

```
NVIDIA(0):Failed to initialize the GLX module; please check in your X log file that the GLX module has been loaded in your XServer, and that the module is the NVIDIA GLX module. If you continue having these problems, please try reinstalling the NVIDIA driver.
```

`lspci -nnk | grep VGA -A1` shows:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]:NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [Geforce 210] [10de:0a65] (rev a2) Subsystem Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:34d5]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]:NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [Geforce 210] [10de:0a65] (rev a2) Subsystem Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:34d5]
```

Was running 12.04 on this machine for more than a year.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to get this issue corrected was **to reinstall my nvidia driver and reboot my PC**. I used the exact same installer I used when I did it the first time last month.

During installation the installer told me that some changes had been made; since the driver was originally installed that was not made. My nvidia and the installer offered to correct the issue the best they could. So it seems to me that some update Ubuntu pushes out is conflicts with the nvidia driver that then causes the login loop. So far all seems good.

Comment: Please, edit your answer and add the entire process.