# Cannot login to 12.04 in the GUI

Tags: 12.04, login, login-screen

I have 12.04 on my machine, and after a shut down and a restart I haven't been able to log into the GUI, after entering my password, it switches back to the GUI and does not accept it.

I've tried the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login via tty1 - worked fine, so the password and user works
- tried to remove the `.Xauthority` file - does not exist
- tried to restart the `lightdm` - no change, still cannot log in
- tried to install the `gdm`, but no apt-get command works, it fails to connect to the required web address
- tried the `sudo chown -R $user:$user /home` command, still cannot log in

Do you have any suggestions what can I do?

Comment: you mean login loop.

Comment: try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/314259/login-loop-ubuntu-12-04) or [_this_](http://askubuntu.com/questions/314362/ubuntu-13-04-login-loop)

Comment: None of them worked :(

Comment: Please post the logs from `/var/log/lightdm/`.